# Ocaml - match n-ary_tree with empty tree

Tags: syntax, tree, ocaml, is-empty

Let's say I have a n-ary tree type

```
type tree = Node of (char*tree) list ref;;
```

and this correspond to the empty tree

```
let empty_tree ()= Node(ref[]);;
```

I'm trying to write a function that only looks if my tree is empty or not, such as

```
let checkIsEmpty t = match t with empty_tree-> print_string "tree is empty";;
```

But when I write `checkIsEmpty empty_tree;;` it just return a unit, it won't print "tree is empty"

I also tried that way

```
let checkisEmpty t = match t with z when z = empty_tree-> print_string "tree is empty";;
```

Sadly it still fails.

How can I look if my tree is empty? I'd like to keep the match with and the way tree is declared (Empty is not part of the type..) if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely need to flush the output to see it. You can write this:

```
print_string "tree is empty"; flush stdout
```

However, your first match doesn't work. Any identifier in a pattern introduces a new variable. So the variable `empty_tree` in your first implementation will always match whatever tree you pass to your function. (Or indeed it will match any value whatsoever.)

The second implementation should work a little better once you add `flush stdout`, and assuming there is a global value `empty_tree` that is an empty tree. But you should also add a case that matches when the tree is *not* empty; otherwise you'll get an exception for that case.

Furthermore your `empty_tree` is a function that returns an empty tree. It's not an empty tree itself (as your latest code is assuming).

(I would suggest you not modify your question too much after asking it. It makes it hard to write an answer that corresponds to what you asked.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yeah I know I should do a case for when it's not empty, but for now I'm only trying to match my tree if the tree passed in my function is equal to the empty_tree, I tried the flush stdout, but it won't work either :( (I tried with the "when" keyword)

Comment: I'm literally doing checkisEmpty empty_tree, and in the function I look if t (which is empty_tree in this case) is equal to empty_tree and it won't write down "tree is empty". Even if I add a case, something like `| _ -> print_string "not empty"; flush stdout` it won't print it

Comment: (Note again that your `empty_tree` is a function, not a tree.) Maybe you're just having trouble getting output at all. What happens if you just execute this: `print_string "testing 1 2 3\n"; flush stdout`? As another side comment, it's easier to see the output if you terminate with `"\n"`, otherwise it can get lost.

Comment: You're right, I must just have trouble getting output at all, your line didn't even printed, I get this output : `- : unit = ()`. I was using this : [link](https://try.ocamlpro.com/) to try my code before running the whole project, however here it works just fine : [link](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.8/files/toplevel/index.html), but my function is still not working. I get that empty_tree is a function, but does that mean I just can't use it this way?

Comment: Equality (`=`) isn't even defined for function types. It definitely makes a difference. My advice: just remove the `()` after `empty_tree`. Then it is a tree, voilà.

Comment: yeah well, that works very well, thanks a lot for your time, I'll go understand a bit more how those kind of function works!